# v-model on composite data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to `Vue.js` and I would like to set some data using a **two-way data binding** via `v-model` (on two separated inputs)

Why I need it: I have two inputs (`input[type=number]` and a `select` containing "days", "months", "years"). And obviously, these two inputs will be concatenated to a data.

Another constraint is that the user is able to add as many "periods" as they want, so the data is a string in an array. Using `v-for="(period, index) in periods"`, it's easy to target a given index in the data array, but it's becoming complicated if I have to use a `computed` with a `get()` exploding the value, and the `set()` concatenating them... But if there is no easier magical way, I'll have to stick to it...

**Example HTML:**

```xml
<agreement inline-template>
    <div v-for="(period, index) in ftc_trial_periods">    
        <input type="number" min="1" v-model="??" required>

        <select v-model="??" required>
            <option>days</option>
            <option>months</option>
            <option>years</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</agreement>
```

**Example Component:**

```java
Vue.component('agreement', {
    data() {
        return {
            ftc_trial_periods: []
        }
    }
});
```

When a number is changed or when an option is selected, I'd like the value to be concatenated/set/appended in `ftc_trial_periods`. For instance, `ftc_trial_periods` could be: `['1 day', '3 months']`.

Comment: Can you add some code to this please, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @chbchb55 I didn't add code previously because I thought it wouldn't add any information, as I don't know how to write in the beginning. Anyway, I have added an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, I would store form values in data and make `ftc_trial_periods` a computed value of these data. So no exploding/concatenating is required.

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/kgodqmbx/6/

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="addPeriod">add period</button><br><br>
    <div v-for="(form) in formInputs">    
        <input type="number" min="1" v-model="form.value" required>

        <select v-model="form.type" required>
            <option>days</option>
            <option>months</option>
            <option>years</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    ftc_trial_periods: {{ftc_trial_periods}}
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    formInputs: [
        {
        value: null,
        type: null
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    ftc_trial_periods: function() {
        return this.formInputs.map(obj => {
        return `${obj.value} ${obj.type}`;
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPeriod: function() {
        this.formInputs.push({
        value: null,
        type: null
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I see where you want to go, and at the end, I understand there is no "easy magical way" to do what I want... Anyway, it's the contrary I need: Push a string in the array (and not 2 distinct values). I can already implement your suggestion in my code, but to accept your answer, you need to change your code a little bit

Answer (score 0):

### Generate `<select>` based on `<input>` with validation

A solution to your problem would be to use a computed value to create `periods` and iterate over this value to create multiple selects with `v-for='index in period`, from here we need to bind the value of each select dynamically in an array `selectedArray: ['']`. To do this I use the computed property `periods` to check for the change in number of periods in the string against the length of `selectedArray`. If there are more periods, I `.push` another string onto `selectedArray`, if there are less, I `.pop` the last one off. To bind each select element I use `v-bind='selectedArray[index]`. Lastly, we validate the string and check that every select is filled out, if so put all the data together in an array of strings.

[Here is the code (below and in JSFiddle):](https://jsfiddle.net/chbchb55/eywraw8t/140674/)

**Vue.js Code:**

```
Vue.component('agreement', {
  template: `
    <div>    
      <input
        type="text"
        v-model="numbers"
      />
      <select
        v-for='index in periods'
        v-model='selectedArray[index - 1]'
        required
      >
        <option>days</option>
        <option>months</option>
        <option>years</option>
      </select>
      <p>
        {{ output }}
      </p>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    numbers: '',
    selectedArray: ['']
  }),
  computed: {
    inputsAreValid: function() {
      return this.numbers.match(/^\d+((\.\d+)?)+$/g) && this.selectedArray.every(selection => selection !== '')
    }, 
    output: function() {
      if (!this.inputsAreValid)
        return []
      return this.numbers.split('.').map((number, index) => `${number} ${this.selectedArray[index]}`)
    },
    periods: function() {
      const numberOfPeriods = this.numbers.split('.').length
      if (numberOfPeriods > this.selectedArray.length)
        this.selectedArray.push('')
      else if (numberOfPeriods < this.selectedArray.length)
        this.selectedArray.pop()
      return numberOfPeriods
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

**HTML Template Code:**

```
<div id="app">
  <agreement></agreement>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this wouldn't suit my needs. It's not the select which is to be stored, but an array of a length and a type of length combination (1 week, 2 months, 9 days, etc...)

Comment: You should check out the JSFiddle link, the output variable contains that kind of result

Comment: What I mean, is that the v-for should be on the div. Both input are to be repeated for each element in the array

Comment: Why? How does that help generate the output?

Comment: How do you handle multiple lines/values in the array?

Comment: I handle multiple values with dots. When you place '.' in the input it generates another `<select>`

Comment: There should be an initial number value and then after each dot an additional number value, this is validated with a regex